# How to disable GO in idea?

Tags: go, intellij-idea, disable

We have some mixed components.
Some are golang, some are java.

The problem is that the `run` view pops up all the time, because go is running, doing a force switch from my current view. The UX issue here is quite obvious as it causing me to context switch, loose concentration and have to manual go back to the view I was before.

Anyhow, I'm in the context of Java for a current task and don't need go at all, not even the whole indexing of the go components.

How can I disable the go integration in IDEA, even though I have go modules in the project?

Comment: Isn't GO support in IntelliJ Idea a plugin? What happens if you disable it?

Comment: Do I need to restart to disable/enable plugins? If so, I prefer a less intrusive way. But it's a valid option!

Comment: That depends on the plugin. Some plugins require a restart, others do not. Jetbrains has improved that a lot. So for Go as a plugin to Idea you should just test it once ;)

Comment: I have all the Go configuration set up. Hope it doesn't get lost on disabling/enabling the whole plugin.

Comment: You can as well set GOROOT to No SDK and exclude the folder with Go files from indexing.

Answer (score -2):

I think I found it. Will update if in some cases it doesn't work.

Down at the bottom, under the Go section there's `Go Modules`.

Uncheck the `Enable Go Modules Integration`.

[image]

Setting itself:

[image]